# Adding form elements with javascript before and after validation in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a customer registration form, it has a button for adding additional phone number fields. After submitting the form and validating the input, the page needs to recreate the same forms with the old inputs. I made the below solution, I would like to know if this is an efficient way and also if I can not create the empty lines, since currently it will recreate all fields even if they were empty.
html

```
<h3>{{__('Phone Numbers')}} <button type="button" id="addPersonPhone">+</button></h3>
<input type="hidden" name="personPhoneLines" id="personPhoneLines" value="{{(old('personPhoneLines')? old('personPhoneLines') : 1)}}">
<div id="personPhone">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class=" col-2">
            <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="personPhoneType-1">{{__('Type')}}</label>
            <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="personPhoneType-1" name="personPhoneType-1">
                <option selected value=''>{{__('Choose')}}...</option>
                @foreach ($phonetypes as $phonetype)
                <option value="{{$phonetype->id}}" {{(old( 'personPhoneType-1')==$ phonetype->id)? "selected":""}}>{{$phonetype->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="personCountryCode-1">{{__('Country')}}</label>
            <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="personCountryCode-1" name="personCountryCode-1">
                <option selected value="">{{__('Choose')}}...</option>
                @foreach ($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{$country->id}}" {{(old( 'personCountryCode-1')==$ country->id)? "selected":""}}>{{$country->name.' (+'.$country->dialing_code.')'}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="personPhoneNo-1">{{__('Number')}}</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="{{__('Number')}}" name="personPhoneNo-1" id="personPhoneNo-1" value="{{old('personPhoneNo-1')}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
var phoneLines = parseInt($("#personPhoneLines").val(), 10);

var phoneRow = $('#personPhone').html();
var oldPersonPhones =["{{old('personPhoneNo-1')}}", "{{old('personPhoneNo-2')}}",
"{{old('personPhoneNo-3')}}", "{{old('personPhoneNo-4')}}", "{{old('personPhoneNo-5')}}"];

for (i = 2; i <= phoneLines; i++) {
    newLine = phoneRow.split('personPhoneType-1').join('personPhoneType-' + i);
    newLine = newLine.split('personCountryCode-1').join('personCountryCode-' + i);
    newLine = newLine.split('personPhoneNo-1').join('personPhoneNo-' + i);

    $("#personPhone").append(newLine);
    $("#personPhoneNo-" + i).val(oldPersonPhones[i-1]);

    }


 $('#addPersonPhone').click(function(){
    if (phoneLines >=5) {
        alert('You cannot add more than 5 lines')
    } else {
        phoneLines = phoneLines + 1;
        newLine = phoneRow.split('personPhoneType-1').join('personPhoneType-'+phoneLines);
        newLine = newLine.split('personCountryCode-1').join('personCountryCode-'+phoneLines);
        newLine = newLine.split('personPhoneNo-1').join('personPhoneNo-'+phoneLines);

    $("#personPhone").append(newLine);
    $("#personPhoneLines").val(phoneLines);

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to change your input name to an array like this:

```
<select name="people[phone_type][]"></select>
<select name="people[phone_country_code][]"></select>
<input type="text" name="people[phone_number][]">
```

This way you can simply duplicate the fields, without needing to name them after something.

Then in your validation you can refer to docs for your fields: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays

And to parse in your controller simply loop them to get the array you need.